# Firestore rules for access to certain docs in a collection, based on subscription

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a posts collection where multiple authors create posts. Those posts can be of two types premium and general.
Premium posts can be read only of the user is subscribers to an author.

Following is the database structure

```
posts/  
**randomid**  
    authorid : 1 
    ispremium : true  
    content : "some content"  
**otherrandomid**  
    authorid : 2  
    ispremium : false  
    content : "some content"  

users/  
 **useruid1**  
   name : 'somename'  
   authorSubscribedByMe  
     1 : true  
 **useruid2**  
   name : 'someothername'  
   authorsSubscribedByMe  
     2 : true
```

I need two types of queries,

1. all general posts

   ```
   ref = db.collection('posts').where('ispremium','==',false)
   ```
2. all premium posts by a particular author

   ```
   ref = db.collection('posts').where('ispremium','==',true)
                               .where('authorid', '==', 1)
   ```

So I am not sure how to create security rules for this. We can check for the subscription by using a get in the security rules, so the second one is easy.
But I read somewhere that firestore evaluates a query before making it, so in this case, it might NEED a filter for the author, and cannot make the query for all general posts. Please guide me on achieving the goal.

Also an optional feature I would like is access to premium post for a specified time. so in users collection, for the authoeSubscribedByMe field, for an authorid, instead of boolean, I will keep a timestamp, so if a subscription is for one month from now, a user can only access till then. Let me know if this is possible.

Comment: You might want to edit the question to show all of the relevant rules and code that you've written so far, and explain how they are not working the way you expect.  Right now, what you're saying is rather broad and it's not very clear where you are stuck.

Comment: From reading your question it seems like you should be able to verify that the query is valid with the information from this page in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query. If you got stuck along the way, show what you've tried.